# Jira REST API - Why there is specialized API for updating status and assignee fields of issue?

Tags: jira-rest-api

I'm learning [Jira REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/8.19.1/).

Table for issue:

[image]

I noticed that there are specialized API for updating `assignee` (`PUT /rest/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/assignee`) and `status` (`POST /rest/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/transitions`) while anoher fields updated by `PUT /rest/issue/{issueIdOrKey}`.

Could you please explain why this happens the way it described above? May be because for `assignee` and `status` fields some validation being performed?

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific 'reason' for it, that's just the way Atlassian have chosen to utilise either PUT versus POST requests to achieve a desired result.

Google "*REST API PUT vs POST*" for more information about the two methods.